# Virtual Machine - Mouse/Keyboard events on Virtual Machine integrate with main machine

Tags: virtual-machine

sorry for bad English. I have a virtual machine and there i installed a software that make some events.
But this events only happens on virtual machine.

Exist any possibility to this events works in my main machine? I mean, an integration between virtual machine and main machine, so when for example my software on virtual machine press "A" keyboard key, on MAIN machine also will happen a "A" press keyboard key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using VMware, VirtualBox, etc , you will need to install the appropriate software on the guest, so you can enable features like, bi-directional copy paste etc.

Once you have this set up you can look up in internet the exact configuration for your hypervisor.

For example here is a working [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/108785/getting-host-to-capture-certain-key-presses-in-virtualbox) for VirtualBox.

VMWare have notoriously bad documentation, also I couldn't find similar feature for the VMPlayer or the workstation. Here is a [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1263419/how-can-i-configure-vmware-workstation-so-that-it-sends-keyboard-shortcuts-to-pr) to get you started

Hope the links are helpful .